# UniSwapV2Router.sol contract failing - "Gas required exceed allowance / Always failing transaction"

Tags: contract-development, contract-debugging, uniswap, defi

I am trying to recreate the Sushiswap protocol for educational reasons, but I am stumbling into an issue. When I try to run the `addLiquidity` function inside the [UniswapV2Router.sol](https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-periphery/blob/master/contracts/UniswapV2Router02.sol) contract with the following arguments:

```
[
    tokenA => "0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7",
    tokenB => "0xEe8A808C478d14aec57f874351177d80D02ce454",
    amountADesired =>"1000000",
    amountBDesired => "100000000000000000",
    amountAMin =>"1000000",
    amountBMin => "100000000000000000",
    to => "0xFFC4d90bCF8C6C1f0FaB5E0e14d03B020B41A701",
    deadline => 1604584008
]
```

The contract fails or runs out of gas. What could be the cause of this? I have linked the UniswapV2Router solidity contract that I deployed above, I haven't made any changes to the code. Below is my deployment procedure on Truffle

```
await deployer.deploy(WETH9);
let weth = await WETH9.deployed();
  
await deployer.deploy(
    UniSwapV2Factory,
    ADMIN_ADDRESS
);

const factory = await UniSwapV2Factory.deployed();
await deployer.deploy(SushiToken);
const sushiToken = await SushiToken.deployed(); 
sushiToken.mint(ADMIN_ADDRESS, web3.utils.toWei("10000000"), { from: ADMIN_ADDRESS });
await deployer.deploy(UniswapV2Router, factory.address, weth.address);
const router = await UniswapV2Router.deployed();
  await deployer.deploy(
    MasterChef,
    sushiToken.address,
    ADMIN_ADDRESS,
    web3.utils.toWei('100'),
    1,
    10
  );
const masterChef = await MasterChef.deployed();
await sushiToken.transferOwnership(masterChef.address);
await deployer.deploy(SushiBar, sushiToken.address);
const sushiBar = await SushiBar.deployed();
await deployer.deploy(
    SushiMaker,
    factory.address,
    sushiBar.address,
    sushiToken.address,
    weth.address
);
const sushiMaker = await SushiMaker.deployed();
await factory.setFeeTo(sushiMaker.address);
  
  //LP migrator stuff
await deployer.deploy(
    Migrator,
    masterChef.address,
    sushiToken.address,
    factory.address,
    1
);
```

What is the best way to dive deeper into debugging this code?

Comment: Do you have a sufficient amount of each token in your account? Also, try to reduce `amountAMin` and `amountBMin` to 1 each. The 'out of gas' error is sometimes the reflection (printout) of your transaction being reverted.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I definitely have enough tokens. I am trying to add 1 Tether and 1 of my own custom token (identical clone of sushiswap) but I am still seeing the error

Comment: I don't see your actual transaction code for executing `addLiquidity`. Where is it? Perhaps you only need to increase the gas-limit.

Comment: Sorry, this code above is just for deploying the contract. I am trying to run the standard sushiswap classic exchange code in this file `https://github.com/sushiswap/sushiswap-classic-exchange/blob/master/src/pages/AddLiquidity/index.tsx`